# The key 'LocalizedPerfCounter' does not exist in the appSettings configuration section

Tags: vb.net, exception, appsettings

I have a desktop application coded in VB.Net with .net 2.0 and then upgraded VS many times and latest framework is 3.5 with VS 2015.

On application start I've noticed an exception in Diagnostic Tool which is caught silently

**The key 'LocalizedPerfCounter' does not exist in the appSettings configuration section.**

Any ideas to fix this problem because this is an application I distribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer on [this](http://securityblog.gr/3382/the-key-localizedperfcounter-does-not-exist/) link and seems it is related to app setting which was missing in app.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="LocalizedPerfCounter" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I needed to add appSettings section after configSections section.